# getting a string value from object

Tags: c#

Hello I have an object which has value "B11" i.e

```
object data = "B11";
```

i have a variable called string resultCell. How do I get B11 into resultCell.

it doesn't seem to work for me in c#. I have tried things like ....

```
resultCell = (string)data;

resultCell =  Convert.ToString(data);
```

**More information**

I am using excel services to get a value in a cell. the excel services returns a object[]. Its a single element though. I want the value in a string. i.e. B11 in the object as string.

Comment: It depends.  What is the object?

Comment: You'll make everyone's lives easier if you provide the error.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the time, calling `data.ToString()` will work. Without the specific type of the `data` object, there isn't any way to answer the question.

Is the value stored in a property of `data`?

Edit: Could you try `(string)object[i]`, where `i` is the index of the particular piece of data you want to retrieve? If you need every value in the array, you'll probably want to use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I am using excel services to get a value in a cell. the excel services returns a object[]. Its a single element though. I want the value in a string. i.e. B11 in the object as string. Hope I have made myself more clear.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to just assign value as data.ToString() to cell.

hope this work for you.